# How do you close the Iris colour picker when you click away from it?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colors

I'm using the [`iris colour picker`](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/) in a Wordpress plugin. I can get it to display and then show the clicked value in the associated input just fine, however there is a problem...

I can't then get rid of the box! Is there a way to make the box disappear when you click off of it?

I'm invoking `iris` using this simple call -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.colour-picker').iris();
});
```

Common sense tells me that I should be able to pass this as an option to the `.iris()` function for this specific need, but I cannot find any reference to such an option in the the [docs](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/).

The closet I have found is that you can call a `hide` method, but all it lists is `$(element).iris('hide');`, with no explanation at all of how to link it to the specific input that invoked `iris` in the first pace, or how to detect if the user has clicked away from `iris`

Does anyone use `iris` and know how I can achieve what I am trying to do? Thanks.

**Additional** - Here is a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFnsB/1/) that demonstrates the problem described. The JS that invokes `iris` can be found right at the bottom of the JS section.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Certainly, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {    
    $('.colour-picker').iris();    
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is(".colour-picker, .iris-picker, .iris-picker-inner")) {
            $('.colour-picker').iris('hide');
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.colour-picker').click(function (event) {
        $('.colour-picker').iris('hide');
        $(this).iris('show');
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFnsB/11/)

Comment: Thanks, we're getting somewhere now. Two issues with this though - 1: I have multiple instances, and clicking from one input that invokes `iris` to another still results in 2x colour pickers. 2: Once `iris` is hidden, it cannot be shown again for that instance (presumably because it's a 'hide' method, not a 'close' method, which seemingly does not exist).

Comment: Sorry, I tested that badly. I've updated the fiddle. I think it covers everything now :)

Comment: Sorry, I've been away from work for a few days. I tested first thing and it appears to have done the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I've added a feature request to the [Iris GitHub page](https://github.com/automattic/Iris/issues) asking for a setting to do this automatically. Hopefully they'll take note, as I'd be amazed if I was the only one who had this problem with it...

Comment: Yes, this should definitely be a OOTB feature.

Comment: This works great, the only part I'll change is the return false; on the document click handler/event because if anything else is clicked , the return false; stops propagation. Maybe it be a link or a label for a checkbox or other click events, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you don't need to call iris directly. As of 3.5, The WordPress core defines a wrapper method called wpColorPicker(), that implements iris with some additional functionality:

http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/

This wrapper takes care of all the hiding and showing of the picker for you, and keeps track of individual instances.

If you're building a WP plugin, it's probably better to use their wrapper, as they will be adding new features to it in the future. Plus, if they decide to go with another library other than iris, your plugin code will likely break. The wrapper will prevent that from happening.

Comment: That helped me a lot. Thanks a lot. <3

Answer (score -1):

you can try like below

```
$('input:not(.colour-picker)').iris('hide');
```

Comment: In what context would I declare that though? Simply declaring it in `ready` will cause an error because I'd be trying to call the method `hide` before `iris` has been initialised.