# How do you close the Iris colour picker when you click away from color picker?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

How do you close the Iris colour picker when you click away from color picker?
I used below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.my-color-picker').iris({
        palettes: true,
        target: false
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you close the Iris colour picker when you click away from it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682706/how-do-you-close-the-iris-colour-picker-when-you-click-away-from-it)

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {    
$('.my-color-picker').iris();    
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is(".my-color-picker, .iris-picker, .iris-picker-inner")) {
        $('.my-color-picker').iris('hide');
        return false;
    }
});
$('.my-color-picker').click(function (event) {
    $('.my-color-picker').iris('hide');
    $(this).iris('show');
    return false;
});
```

});

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vdmw1knL/9/)

Comment: instead of copy pasting code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682706/how-do-you-close-the-iris-colour-picker-when-you-click-away-from-it .. you should mark this as duplicate question.

Comment: and the class OP is using is `.my-color-picker` instead of `.colour-picker` ... you just copied exact same code ... atleast do some changes as per OP's question.

Comment: @Kartikeya so what??? you can mark as duplicate as well. i provide him solution it doesn't matter i copy or not.